# Do I need a model when I have a record?

Tags: plugin-development, records, models

I have a record so I can save my data to the DB but do I need a model for services and stuff ? Or can the record do that too ?

Answer (score 4):

Records *can* do that too (where that = hold data), but, according to [Craft docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/records), Records should never ever leave Service layer. So, yes, you do need a model too.

Comment: +1 Records should never make their way to a view / template.